# Spring Boot application redirects to http URL after successful login

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application with the following security configuration.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      String[] csp = {"default-src 'self'",
                "script-src 'self'",
                "style-src 'self'",
                "img-src 'self'", 
                "font-src 'self'",
                "child-src 'self'",
                "form-action 'self' ",
                "frame-ancestors 'none'",
                "manifest-src 'self'"
        };

      http
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy", String.join(";", csp)))
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/landing");
    }
}
```

I hit the URL `https://my-app.com/login`, enter the correct username and password and click on Login. I get an error message saying

> Refused to send form data to 'http://my-app.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".

I'm not sure why my application redirects to http URL instead of https one. I would like to redirect successful login to https URL

Comment: Are you developing a web (not an rest api) with spring-boot and you just need to render main form if user enter a valid credentials?

Comment: Yes. It's a web application. I intend to show main page on https:// on successful login.

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf?

Comment: Yes. Login page is thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to Spring Boot itself. You have to configure your web server or application server (embedded tomcat in this case I suppose)
Could you please share your application.properties? Have you configured SSL? If yes, you can achieve https redirection through TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory's postProcessContext method by creating a Bean as follows:

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    @Override
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
        securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
        collection.addPattern("/*");
        securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
        context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. My application.yml does not have ssl configured. Could you let me know if these are the properties to be added
```server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: mypassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat```

Answer (score 0):

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** needs a surgical setup and depends of the framework.

For example if your framework automatically creates a page called /authentication instead /login and assets are in folder /media instead the classic /style /font, your configuration will be very different.

In your case, **Thymeleaf** is a classic framework and its security configurations are relies on spring-framework and are well documented:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LoggingAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/",
                            "/js/**",
                            "/css/**",
                            "/img/**",
                            "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("manager").password("password").roles("MANAGER");
    }

}
```

Check this links:

- https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-form-login-example/
- https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-security-thymeleaf-login-logout